# Prove $\limsup(a_n) \geq \limsup(a_{n_k})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$\limsup(a_n) \geq \limsup(a_{n_k})$
I intuitively understand, that this statement is true. And I have clumsy "proof", but I am not sure, whether it's right or not.
Let's assume, that $\limsup(a_n) < \limsup(a_{n_k})$.
Let $A$ be all partial limits of $a_n$, let $A_k$ be all partial limits of $a_{n_k}$.
By definition, $\limsup(a_n) = \sup A$ and $\limsup(a_{n_k}) = \sup A_k$.
From our assumption $\sup A < \sup A_k$.
But $a_{n_k} \subset a_n \implies A_k \subset A \implies \sup A_k \in A_k$ and $ \sup A_k  \in A$.
So $\sup A \geq \sup A_k \iff \limsup(a_n) \geq \limsup(a_{n_k})$. Contradiction.

Does it look alright to you?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine, but it does not require a proof by contradiction. Actually, it's easier to prove the statement *without* contradiction. Just note that the set $A$ of all limits of convergent subsequences of $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ contains the set $A_k$ of all limits of convergent subsequences of $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$. Therefore, $\sup A\geqslant\sup A_k$.

Note that I just wrote the the *idea* is fine. Your proof writing is rather clumsy.